# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, ajax, json

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el siguiente error?

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

En concreto es en la variable `info` que se parsea a un JSON. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo mediante `xmlhttprequest` o en qué estoy fallando.

Aquí les dejo el código correcto js y esto es lo que me ha dado de hacer `console.log(response)`:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\facturacion\sistema\ajax.php</b> on line <b>215</b><br />
error
```

Voy a probar a intentar modificarlo y ahora digo si lo he arreglado.

**Archivo js:**

```
function searchForDetalle(id){
    var action = 'searchForDetalle';
    var user = id;

    $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            method: 'POST',
            async: true,
            data: {action:action, user:user},

            success: function(response){
            console.log(response); 
            if(response != 'error'){
                    // var info = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                    var info = JSON.parse(response);
                    $('#detalle_venta').html(info.detalle);
                    $('#detalle_totales').html(info.totales);

                }else{
                    console.log('no data');
                }    
            },

            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
}
```

**Archivo php:**

```
//Extrae datos detalle_tmp
        if($_POST['action'] == 'searchForDetalle'){
            if(empty($_POST['user'])){
                echo 'error';
            }else{

                $token = md5($_SESSION['idUser']);

                $query = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT tmp.correlativo, tmp.token_user, tmp.cantidad, tmp.precio_venta, p.codproducto, p.descripcion from detalle_tmp tmp INNER JOIN producto p ON tmp.codproducto = p.codproducto where token_user = '$token'");

                $result= mysqli_num_rows($query);

                $query_iva = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT iva from configuracion");
                $result_iva = mysqli_num_rows($query_iva);

                $detalleTabla = '';
                $sub_total = 0;
                $iva = 0;
                $total = 0;
                $arrayData = array();

                if($result > 0){
                    if($result_iva > 0){
                        $info_iva = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_iva);
                        $iva = $info_iva['iva'];
                    }

                    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_detalle_temp)){
                        $precioTotal = round($data['cantidad'] * $data['precio_venta'],2);
                        $sub_total = round($sub_total + $precioTotal,2);
                        $total = round($total + $precioTotal, 2);

                        $detalleTabla .= '<tr>
                                            <td>'.$data['codproducto'].'</td>
                                            <td colspan="2">'.$data['descripcion'].'</td>
                                            <td class="textcenter">'.$data['cantidad'].'</td>
                                            <td class="textright">'.$data['precio_venta'].'</td>
                                            <td class="textright">'.$precioTotal.'</td>
                                            <td class="">
                                                <a href="#" class="link_delete" onclick="event.preventDefault(); del_product_detalle('.$data['codproducto'].');"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>';
                    }

                    $impuesto = round($sub_total * ($iva / 100), 2);
                    $tl_sniva = round($sub_total - $impuesto, 2);
                    $total = round($tl_sniva + $impuesto, 2);

                    $detalleTotales='<tr>
                                        <td colspan="5" class="textright">SUBTOTAL Q.</td>
                                        <td class="textright">'.$tl_sniva.'</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="5" class="textright">('.$iva.'%)</td>
                                        <td class="textright">'.$impuesto.'</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="5" class="textright">TOTAL Q.</td>
                                        <td class="textright">'.$total.'</td>
                                    </tr>';

                    $arrayData['detalle'] = $detalleTabla;
                    $arrayData['totales'] = $detalleTotales;

                    echo json_encode($arrayData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                }else{
                    echo 'error';
                }
                mysqli_close($conection);
            }
            exit;
        }               

    }
    exit;
```

Comment: Hacé un `console.log(response)` como bien dice @FabianSilva. Y arreglá el código PHP que está sobrando una llave si no miré mal.

Comment: Cualquier mensaje de advertencia de PHP (por ejemplo, hacer uso de un índice inexistente) genera un mensaje en HTML que contiene ese carácter del que se está quejando la función `JSON.parse()`. Deberías [editar tu pregunta (pulsando aquí)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/276566/edit) y agregar información acerca del navegador que usas y de la salida de un `console.log(response)` colocado inmediatamente ANTES del `if(response != 'error'){`.

Comment: Hola José. Espero que te tomes tu tiempo para leer mi respuesta y comprender los cambios que te propongo tanto en el código javascript como en el código PHP para que todo funciona correctamente. Creo que la respuesta que has marcado como correcta no soluciona tu problema, sólo te ayudó a encontrar la advertencia de PHP que provoca tu error. Si tienes alguna pregunta no dudes en escribir un comentario en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parece que lo que te esta devolviendo al realizar el ajax no es el json que intentas pasar desde php, en el código

```
var info = JSON.parse(response);
```

debería parsearte correctamente el resultado que envías, prueba hacer antes de esa linea

```
console.log(response);
```

y ver con las herramientas de debug (que usualmente se activan con F12 desde el navegador) ver que devuelve, pues quízas estes recibiendo una pagina en vez de el json esperado, pues si fuera el json que estas enviando con json_enconde desde php, en el success al querer parsear no tiene que fallar.

Comment: Al final era un error de las consultas y variables. Muchas gracias por tu aportación, has conseguido que arreglase mi problema.

Comment: Esta respuesta debería publicarse como comentario ya que no ofrece una solución al problema, sólo pautas para depurar el funcionamiento.

Comment: @OscarGarcia: consideré que brindando pautas para depurar el funcionamiento, acercarian la solucion a su problema, ¿podrias indicarme a tu consideracion como hubiera sido una mejor alternativa de respuesta con los datos que se brindo en la pregunta?

Comment: Puedes ver tanto el comentario que dejé en la pregunta como el contenido de mi respuesta. En ella explico el origen del problema y cómo solucionarlo.

Answer (score 2):

El mensaje de error que estás sufriendo en javascript es debido a que una de tus consultas SQL está generando un error y devuelve `false`:

> `mysqli_num_rows()` expects parameter 1 to be `mysqli_result`, `boolean` given*

Que significa:

> `mysqli_num_rows()` espera que el parámetro 1 sea un `mysqli_result`, pero se proporciona un `boolean`*

Al no capturarlo el código PHP genera ese mensaje y tu código javascript únicamente está preparado para detectar un error como la presencia del texto literal "error", por lo que al hacer `JSON.parse()` del mensaje de advertencia provoca una excepción que tampoco has capturado en javascript.

Te recomiendo que modifiques la parte javascript de la siguiente manera:

```
function searchForDetalle(user) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    method: 'post',
    /* Por defecto javascript crea un índice con el mismo nombre de la variable */
    data: {
      action: 'searchForDetalle',
      user
    },
    success: response => {
      try {
        /* Si el JSON está mal formado se generará una excepción */
        let info = JSON.parse(response);
        if (info.error == true) {
          /* Si hemos enviado por JSON un error, lo notificamos */
          console.log('ERROR detectado:', info);
          return;
        }
        /* Trabajamos habitualmente con la respuesta */
        $('#detalle_venta').html(info.detalle);
        $('#detalle_totales').html(info.totales);
      } catch {
        /* Si el JSON está mal, notificamos su contenido */
        console.log('ERROR. Recibido:', response);
      }
    },
    /* En caso de error XHR mostramos el error (pasará los parámetros a console.log) */
    error: console.log,
  });
}
```

Mejoras que implementa esta versión:

- Asume que todas las respuestas JSON están compuestas de los mismos campos, siendo `info.error` el que almacena un posible estado de error y no un texto plano.
- En caso de error en la obtención del JSON se captura la excepción y se informa de ello en la consola de depuración para su análisos.
- En caso de error general (conexión rechazada, error 404, 500, etc) se envían los datos de error también a la consola de depuración.

También podrías haber hecho uso de [`dataType="json"`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) para que jQuery llame al método de error en caso de que el servidor no devuelva un JSON con su cabecera `Content-Type` asociada y `response` contendría, directamente, los datos devueltos (por ejemplo, `response.error`).

Ahora, tu PHP debería modificarse para detectar errores SQL de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
//Extrae datos detalle_tmp
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'searchForDetalle') {
    if (empty($_POST['user'])) {
        /* Informamos del error */
        die(json_encode([
            'error' => true,
            'detalle' => 'Falta el parámetro "user"',
            'totales' => '',
        ]));
    }
    $token = md5($_SESSION['idUser']);
    $query = mysqli_query($conection, "
        SELECT
            tmp.correlativo,
            tmp.token_user,
            tmp.cantidad,
            tmp.precio_venta,
            p.codproducto,
            p.descripcion
        FROM detalle_tmp tmp
        INNER JOIN producto p
            ON tmp.codproducto = p.codproducto
        WHERE token_user = '$token'
    ");
    if ($query === false) {
        /* Si hubo un error en la consulta SQL devolvemos el error */
        die(json_encode([
            'error' => true,
            'detalle' => 'ERROR en primera consulta: ' . mysqli_error($conection),
            'totales' => '',
        ]));
    }
    $query_iva = mysqli_query($conection, "
        SELECT iva
        FROM configuracion
    ");
    /* Trabamos de obtener el resultado (no es necesario contar el número) */
    $info_iva = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_iva);
    /* Comprobamos si había o no resultados */
    if ($info_iva === false) {
        die(json_encode([
            'error' => true,
            'detalle' => 'Error obteniendo datos del IVA',
            'totales' => '',
        ]));
    }
    $iva = $info_iva['iva'];

    $detalleTabla = '';
    $sub_total = 0;
    $iva = 0;
    $total = 0;
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_detalle_temp)) {
        $precioTotal = round($data['cantidad'] * $data['precio_venta'], 2);
        $sub_total = round($sub_total + $precioTotal, 2);
        $total = round($total + $precioTotal, 2);

        $detalleTabla .= '<tr>
            <td>' . htmlspecialchars($data['codproducto']) . '</td>
            <td colspan="2">' . htmlspecialchars($data['descripcion']) . '</td>
            <td class="textcenter">' . $data['cantidad'] . '</td>
            <td class="textright">' . $data['precio_venta'] . '</td>
            <td class="textright">' . $precioTotal . '</td>
            <td class="">
                <a href="#" class="link_delete" onclick="event.preventDefault(); del_product_detalle(' . json_encode($data['codproducto']) . ');">
                    <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>';
    }
    $impuesto = round($sub_total * ($iva / 100), 2);
    $tl_sniva = round($sub_total - $impuesto, 2);
    $total = round($tl_sniva + $impuesto, 2);
    $detalleTotales = '<tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="textright">SUBTOTAL Q.</td>
        <td class="textright">' . $tl_sniva . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="textright">(' . $iva . '%)</td>
        <td class="textright">' . $impuesto . '</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="textright">TOTAL Q.</td>
        <td class="textright">' . $total . '</td>
    </tr>';
    $arrayData['detalle'] = $detalleTabla;
    $arrayData['totales'] = $detalleTotales;

    /* Indicamos que no hubo error y, además, entregamos los datos */
    die(
        json_encode(
            [
                'error' => false,
                'detalle' => $detalleTabla,
                'totales' => $detalleTotales,
            ],
            JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE
        )
    );
}
```

Los principales cambios que he hecho han sido:

- El JSON devuelto siempre tiene las mismas propiedades:

  - `error`: indica si hubo un error de aplicación o no.
  - `detalle`: tabla de detalle o detalle del error.
  - `totales`: tabla de totales.
- Tras cada consulta **SIEMPRE** compruebo si se ejecutó correctamente y en caso negativo informo enviando la respuesta con `error` a `true` y el mensaje de error SQL en `detalle`.
- No cuento filas para saber si obtuvimos el `IVA` o no, si hacemos un `fetch` y devuelve `false` significa que no se obtuvo ningún resultado.
- Al generar el HTML **SIEMPRE** uso `htmlspecialchars()` para convertir posibles etiquetas HTML (como `<` o `>`) en entidades HTML (como `&gt;` y `&lt`) para evitar XSS y/o que se rompa el diseño de tu tabla.

---

### TL;DR

Ejemplo de que javascript genera una propiedad con el mismo nombre que la variable al crear un objeto. Notar cómo `user` se expande a `user: user`:

```js
let user = 'Usuario';
let datos = {
  action: 'searchForDetalle',
  user
};
// { "action": "searchForDetalle", "user": "Usuario" }
console.log(datos);
```

Pruebas de cómo capturar una excepción al convertir un JSON inválido:

```js
/* Primer ejemplo: JSON mal formado */
let json = `<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in <b>C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\facturacion\\sistema\\ajax.php</b> on line <b>215</b><br />
error`;
try {
  let contenido = JSON.parse(json);
  console.log('Contenido analizado:', contenido);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('ERROR en JSON:', e.message);
}

/* Segundo ejemplo: JSON correcto */
json = '{ "action": "searchForDetalle", "user": "Usuario" }';
try {
  let contenido = JSON.parse(json);
  console.log('Contenido analizado:', contenido);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('ERROR en JSON:', e.message);
}
```