# Error en parse JSON Unexpected token

Tags: php, jquery, json

**ERROR OBTENIDO**

> VM205:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object.success (index.php:32)
>       at i (jquery.min.js:631)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:634)
>       at A (jquery.min.js:1599)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:1628)

**Código Utilizado**

```
<?php
$conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("802",$conexion);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios", $conexion);
$array = array();
if($result){
    while ($row =  mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $Nombres =  utf8_encode($row['ApellidoPaterno']);
        array_push($array, $Nombres); //nombres

    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Autocomplete</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.migrate.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css">

</head>
<body>

    <input id="tag">
    <br>
    <label>Nombre: </label>
    <h2 id="nombre"> </h2>
    <li id="results"></li>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
            var items = <?= json_encode($array); ?>

            $("#tag").autocomplete({
                source: items,
                select: function(event, item){
                    var params = {
                        nombre: item.item.value
                    };
                    //ajax
                    $.get("getodo.php",params, function(response){

                        var json = JSON.parse(response);
                        if(json.status == 200){
                            $("#nombre").html(json.nombre);

                        }else{
                        }
                    }); //ajax

                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Causa del Error**
Tengo un error al momento de imprimir el `JSON` después de seleccionar algún valor del `autocomplete`.

Comment: Si imprimes response con `JSON.stringify(response)` que muestra? Puedes incluirlo en la publicación?

Comment: No muestra nada, me da error totalmente 

Comment: El problema esta ahí entonces, porque estas tratando de _parsear_ un elemento que viene `undefined`; primero debes asegurarte que llegue algo para poder trabajar con él. Revisa bien la forma en que estas obteniendo `$array` y si este afirmativamente devuelve los datos que necesitas

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/276566/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0)

Answer (score -1):

Debes asignar la variable `items` de esta manera:

```
var items = <?= echo json_encode($array); ?>
```