# Aparece un error Unexpected token < in JSON y no sé por qué me sale

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo mi código y ya había convertido objetos a *json* para poder insertarlos a la base de datos, pero ahora me sale este error:

> ```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
>        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>        at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (app.js:121)``
> ```

Así que hice un `console.log(xhr.responsetext)` y me salió esto:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: accion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\agendaphp\inc\modelos\modelo-contactos.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />

    {"id":"84","accion":"borrar"}
```

Como pueden ver, está el objeto convertido en *json* pero se le adjunta un error arriba y eso hace que salga el error.

Éste es mi PHP:

```
<?php
      if($_POST['accion'] == 'crear'){ 
               //creará un nuevo registro en labase de datos
              require_once('../funciones/bd.php');
              //validar las entradas
              $nombre = filter_var($_POST['nombre'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
              $empresa = filter_var($_POST['empresa'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
              $telefono = filter_var($_POST['telefono'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

               try{
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO contactos (nombre, empresa, telefono) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ");
                    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $nombre, $empresa, $telefono);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    if($stmt->affected_rows == 1){
                        $respuesta = array(
                            'respuesta' => 'correcto',
                            'datos' => array(
                                'nombre' => $nombre,
                                'empresa' => $empresa,
                                'telefono' => $telefono,
                                'id_insertado' => $stmt->insert_id
                            ) 
                        );
                    }
                    $stmt->close();
                    $conn->close();
               }catch(Exception $e) {
                    $respuesta = array(
                        'error' => $e->getMessage()

                    );
               }
               echo json_encode($respuesta);
           }
        ?>

        <?php 
           if($_GET['accion'] == 'borrar'){
               echo json_encode($_GET);
           }

       ?>
```

Ésta es mi función, que ya tenía antes de insertar contacto en la base de datos:

```
function insertarBD(datos){
                //lammado a ajax 

                //crear el objeto
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                //abrir la conexion
                xhr.open('POST', 'inc/modelos/modelo-contactos.php', true);
                //pasar los datos
                xhr.onload = function(){    
                    if(this.status === 200){
                        const respuesta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        //insertar los datos a la tabla
                        const nuevoContacto = document.createElement('tr');
                        nuevoContacto.innerHTML = `
                        <td>${respuesta.datos.nombre}</td>
                        <td>${respuesta.datos.empresa}</td>
                        <td>${respuesta.datos.telefono}</td>
                        `;
                        const contenedorAcciones = document.createElement('td');

                        //crear icono editar

                        const iconoEditar = document.createElement('i');
                        iconoEditar.classList.add('fas', 'fa-pen-square');
                        //crea el enlace para editar
                        const btnEditar = document.createElement('a');
                        btnEditar.appendChild(iconoEditar);
                        btnEditar.href = `editar.php?id=${respuesta.datos.id_insertado}`;
                        btnEditar.classList.add('btn', 'btn-editar');
                        contenedorAcciones.appendChild(btnEditar);

                        // crear icono eliminar 
                        const iconoEliminar = document.createElement('i');  
                        iconoEliminar.classList.add('fas', 'fa-trash-alt');

                        //crear el bnoton de eliminar
                        const btnEliminar = document.createElement('button');
                        btnEliminar.appendChild(iconoEliminar);
                        btnEliminar.setAttribute('data-id', respuesta.datos.id_insertado)
                        btnEliminar.classList.add('btn', 'btn-borrar');


                        //agregar al padre
                        contenedorAcciones.appendChild(btnEliminar);

                        //agregarlo al tr 
                        nuevoContacto.appendChild(contenedorAcciones);

                        //agregarlo con los contactos
                        listadoContactos.appendChild(nuevoContacto);
                        //mostrar notificacion
                        mostrarNotificacion('contacto creado correctamente', 'correcto');
                        //resetear formulario
                        document.querySelector('form').reset();
                    }

            } 
                //enviar los datos
                xhr.send(datos);
```

Ésta es mi nueva función:

```
//Eliminar contacto 
    function eliminarContacto(e){
     if( e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('btn-borrar') ){
         //Saber el id 
        const id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
        //console.log(id);
        //PREGUNTAR AL USUARIO SI ESTAN SEGUROS
        const respuesta = confirm('¿Estas seguro que deseas eliminar este registro?');
        if(respuesta){
           //llamado a ajax
            //crear el objeto
           const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            //abrir la conexion 
            xhr.open('GET', `inc/modelos/modelo-contactos.php?id=${id}&accion=borrar`, true);
            //leer la respuesta 
            xhr.onload = function(){
                if(this.status == 200){ 
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    const resultado = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                    console.log(resultado);
                }
            }
            //enviar la peticion
            xhr.send();
        }
     }
    }
```

Si borro en PHP el primer `if` funciona el otro (no sale el error), ¿alguno sabe por qué sale ese error que se adjunta a mi json?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/276566/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0)

Comment: En tu función de xhr envias un `GET` y en php esperas `POST`

Comment: Exacto @JonathanOrta, eso es lo que provoca que no exista el índice y aparezca esa advertencia, pero hay que darle solución comprobando previamente su existencia.

Comment: no, tengo dos funciones una para _POST y otra para _GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que intentas acceder al índice `accion` de la matriz `$_POST` sin comprobar previamente su existencia:

> Undefined index: `accion`

En castellano:

> Índice no definido: `accion`

---

La forma correcta de hacerlo sería, por ejemplo:

```
if (isset($_POST['accion']) && $_POST['accion'] == 'crear') {
```

Además, estás enviando la variable por `GET` y no por `POST`, por lo que sería:

```
if (isset($_GET['accion']) && $_GET['accion'] == 'crear') {
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias me sirvió, lo que si no entiendo es por que sirve, ya que la variable existía y el código aunque no lo verificase se ejecutaba pero aparecía como no definida

Comment: Porque estás enviando la variable por `GET` (`modelo-contactos.php?accion=borrar`). Todo lo que se manda a través de la URL va a la variable `$_GET` y no `$_POST` como habías puesto.